# Java parse date

Tags: java, date, parsing

This is my date. 
`Fri, 25 Sep 2015 12:01:16 +0000`

The output should look like this.
`2015-09-25 12:01:16`

This does not work.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E, d M y H:m:s X");
```

I need it to be converted to mysql date.

I have this error

```
Exception in thread "main" 
java.text.ParseException:Unparseable date: "25 Sep 2015 12:01:16"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
at Main.main(Main.java:27)
```

Comment: Whar do you mean by convert to mysql date?

Comment: What do you mean "does not work"? What happens? What do you do with the `sdf` after you define it? How do you convert it to `java.sql.Date`? Please show more code.

Comment: You might read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) if you haven't already.

Comment: And/Or [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html)

Comment: If your date has a FIXED format: `WWW, DD MMM YYYY HH:MM:SS +NNNN" it might be better to use `String` manipulation function called `substring`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your format is off, you need three `M`(s) to get the abreviated month name (using one gives the numeral value). Something like,

```
String str = "Fri, 25 Sep 2015 12:01:16 +0000";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E, d MMM y H:m:s X");
try {
    System.out.println(sdf.parse(str));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And I get a valid `Date`. As for debugging the above, a quick and dirty way to verify your format is something like

```
System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date())); // <-- check your format pattern
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming fixed given date and time string of exactly this form--

`WWW, DD MMM YYYY HH:MM:SS +NNNN`

--this should work:

```
public class Date2Date
{
  static String month(String s)
  {
    switch(s.substring(8,11).toLowerCase()){
      case "jan": return "01";
        // etc.
      case "sep": return "09";
        // etc.
      case "nov": return "11";
    }
    return "12";
  }
    public static void main (String args []) {

      String str ="Fri, 25 Dec 2015 12:01:16 +0000";
                 //0123456789012345678901234567890      

      System.out.println(str.substring(12,16) + "-" + month(str) + "-" + 
                         str.substring(5,7) + " " + str.substring(17,25));
    }
}
```

If the fields are NOT fixed in length, read up on `indexOf` and other `String` functions. I think SOME editing of input has to be done to use `SimpleDateFormat`, but I could be wrong.